# What is the different between go over all my list through loop compare to list.Where(...)

Tags: c#

For example:

```
public void do1(string str)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        if (item == str)
        {
            ///
        }
    }
}
```

Compare to:

```
public void do2(string str)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    var item = list.Where(x => x == str);
    ///
}
```

What is the most effective way to implement a collection search ?

Comment: .Where is implemented using for each. They are equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "most effective"?

Using Linq (`list.Where()`) gives you more succinct and arguably more maintainable code, it also makes it easier to see the human-logic behind your program as you're using high-level operations.

Using `foreach` does have a *miniscule* performance bonus, and does give you more flexibility if you're performing more complicated operations than can be described with Linq, such as implementing a state-machine.

If you want to do a simple, single-term search, then using `.Where` is acceptable and I see no reason to use `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no other way faster than a simple `foreach` loop. You can't achieve better performance than linear searching through a list if the list has no special properties.

The benefit of the Linq's `.Where` and `.Single` (and their cousins) is simply because it's much more concise and satisfying to read a well written `.Single` search than writing a foreach method with many if statements.

Imagine having

```
Model object = null;
foreach (var model in modelsList) {
    if (model != null && model.Property != null && model.Property.Property == "wanted") {
        object = model;
    }
}
```

versus

```
Model object = modelsList.Single(model =>
        model != null && 
        model.Property != null && 
        model.Property.Property == "wanted"
);
```

and you see the idea a bit better.

In reality, the performance differences will be negligible, but it's safe to say that a `foreach` would be marginally faster at worst.